# Python - failure u202c

Tags: python, email, gmail

First up, a confession - I'm not a developer. My developer just left and a piece of code we require is failing, so I'm really hoping someone here can point out how to fix. Essentially, the code queries a gmail account to extract data from specific format emails and deliver them in a csv file. I believe it is a rogue character somewhere in the gmail data. My question is how can I identify which email contains the rogue character? I have narrowed down the date range, so know the issue exists within 250 records, but I can't visually identify which one.

Here is the failure message:

```
Authentication successful.
Messages total: 257
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./extract_billing_from_gmail.py", line 579, in <module>
    csvwriter.writerow([ lead_customer, lead['client_id'], lead['operator_name'], lead['chat_id'], lead['time'], lead['date'], email_time, email_date, timelag_minutes, lead['out_of_hours'], lead['type'],  lead['area_to_rent_or_buy'], lead['area_to_sell_or_let'], lead['name'], lead['email'], lead['phone'], lead['phone2'], email_subject_plaintext ])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u202c' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
Admins-MacBook-Pro:OCSL_created_gmail_billing andy$
```

Each email is in the following format:
Subject -- Yomdel Live Lead - [name of client]

Then the body contains the following:

Operator name: Jane

Checked by: Oliver

Client ID: XXXXX James

Time: 10:41am

Date: 20-01-2016

Chat ID: O1Q86YL8T3

Name: Sophie XXXXX

Phone: 07917 000000

Email: sophie.x.xxxxxx@hotmail.co.uk

Customer type: Buyer/Seller

Property type: 3 bed (To buy)

Budget: £325,000

Following this there are a couple of lines to describe requirements.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code you are running?

Comment: [U+202C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/) is a bidi control. Your code probably isn't prepared to cope with Hebrew/Arabic input (or actually non-English text of any kind). Without access to the code, we can only point you to http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here will be to wrap line 579 in a try/except block and print out the subject, then re-raise the error:

```
try:
    csvwriter.writerow([ lead_customer, lead['client_id'], lead['operator_name'], lead['chat_id'], lead['time'], lead['date'], email_time, email_date, timelag_minutes, lead['out_of_hours'], lead['type'],  lead['area_to_rent_or_buy'], lead['area_to_sell_or_let'], lead['name'], lead['email'], lead['phone'], lead['phone2'], email_subject_plaintext ])
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print 'Failed to parse {}.'.format(email_subject_plaintext.encode('utf-8', 'replace')
    raise
```

This should help you identify the offending email by the subject line.  Of course any other identifying information you want could be added in there as well - the key is of course ensuring it's properly encoded to print.

That gets to the larger issue, which is that it seems that before you pass the bits of data to the csvwriter that they should be properly encoded - something similar to the `.encode()` call that I showed in the print statement needs to be done for each bit of data going out, and that should allow the script to run even when it encounters funky characters.